# How to delete a private page added by spam in WordPress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

A WordPress site affected by spam and added private page but not listing in the pages tab. But it's showing count as 1 in the pages tab.
[image]
[image]

How can I delete that page from Wordpress, because it's opening some spam page automatically when loading any site's page from Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that it is **SPAM**, then deleting the post created by SPAM will not solve your problem. However, there are solutions-

1. Remove all the nulled themes and plugins
2. Install [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/sucuri-scanner/)
   free plugin and run full scan
3. Follow the scan result instructions